# Como crear un boton en PHP para retornar a la página principal?

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en programació y tengo una consulta:

Estoy creando un Sistema basico, tengo dos paginas index.php (principal) y article.php
quiero crear un boton en article.php para regresar a index.php

gracias de antemano

Comment: Que has investigado?

Comment: Podrías colocar el código que tienes hasta ahora? Realiza el [tour] para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Revisa también [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Puedes agregar algo tan simple como una etiqueta `<a href="index.php">Inicio</a>`

Comment: Esta pregunta carece hasta de una simple búsqueda en Google, además la respuesta aceptada promueve una práctica, claramente porque faltaba información y el título no es claro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pues tienes tres opciones, una es envolver el botón con un enlace, otra es crear un enlace y darle estilo como si fuera un botón y otra opción es crear un botón y redireccionar con JavaScript.

Opción 1:

```php
<a href="index.php"><button type="button">VOLVER</button></a>
```

Opción 2:

```php
<style>
.boton {
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
}
</style>
<a href="index.php" class="boton">VOLVER</a>
```

Opción 3:

```php
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php'">VOLVER</button>
```

Comment: Hola Manu, utilice las 3 opciones y me funcionaron a la perfección, mil gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Esta respuesta va parcialmente en contra de las buenas prácticas de la W3C, un `<button>` no debe estar dentro de un `<a>`. Además la pregunta carecía de información y esfuerzo. -1

Answer (score -1):

Hay varias opciones y depende del escenario. La opción más sencilla pudiera ser un botón con acción de javascript:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php';" value="Inicio" />
```

Hay otras formas, lo puedes ver [aquí.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: El voto negativo (no fue de mi parte) pero es debido a que la pregunta no muestra una investigación previa y/o lo que ha realizado.

Comment: Hola Cesar, si me funcionó tambien, excelente.